Rayleigh Quotient as argmin
Background
Rayleigh Quotient are defined as
$$r(x):=\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$$
Prove that
$$r(x)=\arg\min_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}||Ax-\lambda x||_2$$
Attempts

Multiplying the minimized function by $||\frac{x^T}{x^Tx}||$ and arranging the terms, gets $\lambda=\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$. This result indeed sets the later function to 0. Was hoping to get more than 0.
Taking derivative by $\lambda$ of the norm and comparing to 0. However, the derivative I got is
$$2\lambda x^Tx-x^TAx-x(Ax)^T=0$$
Which does't seem exactly like $\lambda=\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$

Questions

Is it possible that Rayleigh Quotient actually zero out the $||Ax-\lambda x||_2$ rather than minimizing it?
How can Rayleigh Quotient be derived from equating the derivative of $||Ax-\lambda x||_2$ to 0?


Here is a related post
